# unwanted data saved after clearing the graph.

Tags: matlab, user-interface, signals, system

I am using a matlab gui to perform some signal manipulation with phase lock loops and I cannot seem to figure out in my code where the data is being saved even though I believe to have removed it.

Here are the files http://sdrv.ms/ZO5hXD

Below is the setting function.

```
function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
position = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
x = position(1);
y = position(3);
%handles.poles=handles.sVar;
%handles.zeros=handles.sVar;
%guidata(hObject,handles);
slType = get(handles.figure1 ,'SelectionType');


if(strcmp(slType,'normal'))
        if(y<0.05 && y>-0.05)
            line(x,y,'marker','X','HitTest','off');
            handles.poles=handles.poles*(handles.sVar-x-y)
            guidata(hObject, handles);
        else
            line(x,y,'marker','X','HitTest','off');
            line(x,-y,'marker','X','HitTest','off');
            handles.poles=handles.poles*(handles.sVar-x-y)*(handles.sVar-x+y);
            guidata(hObject, handles);
        end

else
    line(x,y,'marker','O','HitTest','off');
    handles.zeros=handles.zeros*((handles.sVar-x-y)*(handles.sVar-x+y));
    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

update(hObject,handles);
set(hObject,'buttondownfcn',{@axes1_ButtonDownFcn,handles});
```

Below are the callbacks to remove the data.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
guidata(hObject,handles);
delete(findobj(handles.axes1,'Type','line','Marker','X'));
handles.poles=handles.sVar;
guidata(hObject, handles);
update(hObject,handles);



% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
guidata(hObject,handles);
delete(findobj(handles.axes1,'Type','line','Marker','O'));
handles.zeros=handles.sVar;
guidata(hObject, handles);
update(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: I downloaded the file and this appears to be working... could you elaborate on your problem a little more? Pressing the pushbuttons clear the poles and zeros.

Comment: Once I try to plot another pole or zero after the plane has been cleared from the graph it seems that different data is being plotted.